# How I can detect drag gestures google map in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I have toggle button to reset camera to current user location and also trucking user, when user changed location also update camera to this, now I want on user dragged map this tracking listener dismiss. until click the button again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `cameraPositionState.cameraMoveStartedReason`

```
if (cameraPositionState.cameraMoveStartedReason == GESTURE) {
    // movement by user
}
```

Comment: If you find don't see the `cameraMoveStartedReason` property on the `cameraPositioinState` (like me) then make sure you are using at least [`v2.4.0`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/releases/tag/v2.4.0) of `com.google.maps.android:maps-compose` because that is when this feature was added.

Comment: You don't need to import all gestures, just use `CameraMoveStartedReason.GESTURE`